# How to get Rule Data from Business Central Drools

Tags: java, drools, kie

I am using business central and Drools 7.49. I have configured my rules through Business Central and I am able to fire the rules and get the result successfully. Now what I need is an API preferably returning a JSON containing all the rules description as I want to show the rules set in Business Central my space, project and package.

Is there a way I could get the rules details that I have configured.

Do let me know if any additional information is required.
Here is my project details.
Space: iot-platform-space
Project:  iot-temperature-service
Container: IOTTreeContainer

Below is the code I am having to connect to Business Central

```
URL = http://x.x.x.x:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server

KieServicesConfiguration conf = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(URL, USER, PASSWORD);

KieServicesClient kieServicesClient = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(conf);
```

I want an object of KieContainer from this to get all the rules.

Here is the code to get the rules.

```
KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
        Collection<KiePackage> kiePackages = kieBase.getKiePackages();
List<Rule> ruleList = kiePackages.stream().flatMap(kiePackage -> kiePackage.getRules().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to get KieContainer object from kieServiceClient or any other way to get it.

Comment: Could you help us with the imports? I can't find `KieServicesConfiguration` and `KieServicesClient` in drools 7.49 version. What dependency am I missing here.?

Comment: @ArunGowda It is in kie-server-client-7.49.0.Final.jar Dependency <dependency>
   <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
   <artifactId>kie-server-client</artifactId>
   <version>7.49.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Here are the imports import org.kie.server.client.KieServicesClient;
import org.kie.server.client.KieServicesConfiguration;

Answer (score 2):

The [Business Central REST API](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.52.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#knowledge-store-rest-api-con_drl-rules) is what you are looking for.

With this API you can get your projects and the git URL of each of them. If you want, you can then use a git client to access the project assets.

Another possibility is to use the [KIE Server REST APIs](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.52.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#kie-server-rest-api-endpoints-ref_kie-apis), but I never used them before. The documentation mentions a Swagger endpoint that you can use to see what information is available through these endpoints.

Comment: I looked into the whole chapter but there is no endpoint to get the rules in a specific project and space. Could you point me one.

Comment: I've added more info in the response

Comment: I looked into the KIE Server REST APIs but there is no way I could find here where I could get the rules, is there anything I am missing